# AlphaAnimation Rotates Framelayout in KitKat

Tags: android, android-animation, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a simple activity that spins an arrow to a random angle, and when the arrow stops spinning it flashes. The flashing effect is an alpha animation applied to an `imageview` of a lit version of the arrow.

It works just fine in `Lollipop` and above, but in `KitKat` when the alpha animation is applied it negates the `setFillAfter` of the completed rotation animation and the arrows instantly change to pointing straight up (0 degrees)

```
  public void Spin2 ()
    {
        spinning = true;
        degreeEnd = rnd.nextInt(360);

        RotateAnimation spinIt = new RotateAnimation(0,3600+degreeEnd, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        spinIt.setDuration(6000);
        spinIt.setFillAfter(true);
        spinIt.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        spinIt.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                arrowLit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                animBlink = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
                animBlink.setDuration(500);
                animBlink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator() );
                animBlink.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

                // in KitKat this animation seems to reset the rotation..
                arrowLit.startAnimation(animBlink);

                spinning = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        theSpinner.startAnimation(spinIt);

    }
```

Interestingly,  when you start the spinning again it flicks back to where it should be (degreeEnd) and starts the spin from there.

It is like it is temporarily overriding the `setFillAfter` of the rotation.   I have tried various combinations of `setFillBefore` etc on the animations.  Also, if I set the blinking animation to a finite number (eg 4) it will stop and stay at the zero - it won't correct until i re-spin.

Again, this works just fine in API 20 and up.

Thanks for any help

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be something to do with the `Frame Layout`. Once it was out of the equation it works fine on KitKat.